# Using chrome push notifications mainfest.json in meteor project

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-cloud-messaging

I am following a guide on how to implement the [chrome push notification](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en) and I am trying to implement it in a Meteor app as a package.

Because I am unable to include the manifest.json I am getting "Registration failed - no sender id provided" or "Registration failed - permission denied". So how can I include this file in my project?

The manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
  "permissions": [ "gcm" ],
  "name": "push",
  "short_name": "push notification",
  "display": "standalone",
  "gcm_sender_id": "0000000000000"
}
```

I have tried including it with the package.js like:

```
api.addAssets('manifest.json', 'client');
```

And also put the required variables (gcm_sender_id) in settings.json and starting meteor with `meteor --settings settings.json` but nothing works.

My service worker registration starts with calling `Cpn.serviceWorkerRegistration`:

```
Cpn = {};

Cpn.serviceWorkerRegistration = function () {
  console.log("serviceWorkerRegistration called");

  subscribe();
  console.log(navigator);

  // Check that service workers are supported, if so, progressively  
  // enhance and add push messaging support, otherwise continue without it.  
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
      .then(initialiseState);
  } else {
    console.warn('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.');
  }
}

// Once the service worker is registered set the initial state  
initialiseState = function () {
  console.log("initialiseState");

  // Are Notifications supported in the service worker?  
  if (!('showNotification' in ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype)) {
    console.warn('Notifications aren\'t supported.');
    return;
  }

  // Check the current Notification permission.  
  // If its denied, it's a permanent block until the  
  // user changes the permission  
  if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    console.warn('The user has blocked notifications.');
    return;
  }

  // Check if push messaging is supported  
  if (!('PushManager' in window)) {
    console.warn('Push messaging isn\'t supported.');
    return;
  }

  // We need the service worker registration to check for a subscription  
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    // Do we already have a push message subscription?  
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then(function (subscription) {
        if (!subscription) {
          return;
        }

        // Keep your server in sync with the latest subscriptionId
        sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.warn('Error during getSubscription()', err);
      });
  });
}

function subscribe() {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()
      .then(function (subscription) {
        // The subscription was successful
        // TODO: Send the subscription.endpoint to your server  
        // and save it to send a push message at a later date
        return sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
          // The user denied the notification permission which  
          // means we failed to subscribe and the user will need  
          // to manually change the notification permission to  
          // subscribe to push messages  
          console.warn('Permission for Notifications was denied');
        } else {
          // A problem occurred with the subscription; common reasons  
          // include network errors, and lacking gcm_sender_id and/or  
          // gcm_user_visible_only in the manifest.  
          console.error('Unable to subscribe to push.', e);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

And the service worker looks like this:

```
self.addEventListener('push', showNotification)
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', closeNotificationAndOpenWindow)

function showNotification(event) {
  console.log('Received a push message', event)

  var title = 'Yay a message.'
  var body = 'We have received a push message.'
  var icon = '/images/icon-192x192.png'
  var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag'

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: body,
      icon: icon,
      tag: tag
    })
  )
}

function closeNotificationAndOpenWindow(event) {
  console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag)
  // Android doesn’t close the notification when you click on it
  // See: http://crbug.com/463146
  event.notification.close()

  // This looks to see if the current is already open and
  // focuses if it is
  event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
    type: "window"
  }).then(function (clientList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
      var client = clientList[i]
      if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)
        return client.focus()
    }
    if (clients.openWindow)
      return clients.openWindow('/')
  }))
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code showing the issue

Comment: I put the `manifest.json` in the public folder and added `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">` inside a head tag, and suddenly it worked. I had tried this before without any result. I do not know why it works now, it may have been because of the JSON files encoding option?

Comment: Have you managed to make a push notification services with the worker ?

Comment: Yes, I put the `service-worker.js` and `manifest.json` in the public folder, then I were able to subscribe to push notifications from my package. I did not need to add any of these files to my packages `package.js`. Also see my comment above.